# How to change <li> to <input> then back to <li> with new value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to turn all `div` elements within each `li` into an input when the **Edit** button is clicked. Then when **Save** is clicked, all the inputs revert back to a `div` and save the new value that is in the input. The issue I have is that the top input value gets saved to all `div` elements. I want each value to save to its own `div`. For example, if the top `li div` is left unchanged and the bottom is changed to a new value, that new value will only save to the bottom `li div`.

Pretty new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function toInput() {
    var inner = document.querySelector('.listItem div');
    console.log(inner);
    $('.listItem div').replaceWith('<input value="' + inner.innerHTML + '">' );  
}

function saveInput() {
    var inputVal = $('.listItem input').val();
    console.log(inputVal);
    $('.listItem input').replaceWith('<div>' + inputVal + '</div>' );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data">
    <li class="listItem">
        Test 1: <div>Item 1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
        Test 2: <div>Item 1</div>
    </li>
</ul>
<button class='save' onclick="saveInput();">Save</button>
<button class='edit' onclick="toInput();">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: I haven't, I will give it a try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like

```
function saveInput() {
  $(".listItem").each(function(){
   text = '<div>'+$(this).find('input').val()+'</div>'; // Capture the data first and store in a variable called as text. Enclose it with div tags as for second round you need that.
   $(this).find('input').remove(); // remove the input
   $(this).append(text); // append the text to listItem
  })
```

I am not comfortable with inbuilt code snippet on this.

Here is your reference working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qyL6r341/

Comment: creating snippet is really no different than creating a fiddle. Similar library selection and panels to insert script, html and css

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the selected inputs like this:

```js
function toInput() {
  var inner = document.querySelector('.listItem div');
  console.log(inner);
$('.listItem div').replaceWith('<input value="' + inner.innerHTML + '">' );  
}

function saveInput() {
  var inputVal = $('.listItem input');
  inputVal.each(function(i, input) {
    $(input).replaceWith('<div>' + $(input).val() + '</div>' );
  });
  console.log(inputVal);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data">
      <li class="listItem">
       Test 1: <div>Item 1</div>
      </li>
      <li class="listItem">
       Test 2: <div>Item 1</div>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <button class='save' onclick="saveInput();">Save</button>
      <button class='edit' onclick="toInput();">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toInput() {
  var inner = document.querySelectorAll('.listItem div');
  $(inner).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).replaceWith('<input value="' + $(this).text()+ '">' );
  });
}

function saveInput() {
  var inner = document.querySelectorAll('.listItem input');
  $(inner).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).replaceWith('<div>' + $(this).val()+ '</div>' );
  });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data">
      <li class="listItem">
       Test 1: <div>Item 1</div>
      </li>
      <li class="listItem">
       Test 2: <div>Item 2</div>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <button class='save' onclick="saveInput();">Save</button>
      <button class='edit' onclick="toInput();">Edit</button>
```